# Is it possible to use Portable Class Libraries(PCL) with Visual Studio Online hosted build server?

Tags: tfsbuild, portable-class-library, azure-devops

I'm trying to use the Hosted Builder server from Visual Studio Online.
I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Everything works fine until I'm including a Portable Class Library (PCL).
I get errors related to the AssemblyInfo.cs file:

```
Source\TestprojectSolution\TestprojectPCL\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs (9, 12)
        The type or namespace name 'AssemblyTitle' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    Source\TestprojectSolution\TestprojectPCL\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs (10, 12)
    The type or namespace name 'AssemblyDescription' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    Source\TestprojectSolution\TestprojectPCL\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs (11, 12)
    The type or namespace name 'AssemblyConfiguration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    Source\TestprojectSolution\TestprojectPCL\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs (12, 12)
    The type or namespace name 'AssemblyCompany' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    Source\TestprojectSolution\TestprojectPCL\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs (13, 12)
    The type or namespace name 'AssemblyProduct' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    Source\TestprojectSolution\TestprojectPCL\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs (14, 12)
    The type or namespace name 'AssemblyCopyright' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    Source\TestprojectSolution\TestprojectPCL\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs (15, 12)
    The type or namespace name 'AssemblyTrademark' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    Source\TestprojectSolution\TestprojectPCL\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs (16, 12)
    The type or namespace name 'AssemblyCulture' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    Source\TestprojectSolution\TestprojectPCL\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs (17, 12)
    The type or namespace name 'NeutralResourcesLanguage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    Source\TestprojectSolution\TestprojectPCL\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs (29, 12)
    The type or namespace name 'AssemblyVersion' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Is it possible to use a PCL togehter with the hosted build server? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: Open the AssemblyInfo.cs file, right click on the AssemblyTitle attribute in the line [assembly: AssemblyTitle("name")] and select 'Go to definition', please have a check which assembly is referenced.

Comment: I have the same issue as Tim so if I may: going to definition results in the following for me: Assembly System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a (local path: .nuget\packages\System.Runtime\4.0.20\ref\dotnet\System.Runtime.dll)

Comment: I'm sorry, I had to remove the PCL and replace it with a normal class lib. Still no clue though....

Comment: Would love to hear an answer, Vicky. Same problem here. Resharper took me to:
// Decompiled with JetBrains decompiler
// Type: System.Reflection.AssemblyTitleAttribute
// Assembly: mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
// MVID: 60C8914F-EAF9-4641-8F9D-EEA81508716F
// Assembly location: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll

Answer (score 4):

I just answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33571729/1123431

The reason this is happening is because the version of NuGet on the Build Agent is not sufficient enough to generate a `project.lock.json` file from a `project.json` file.  Until Microsoft updates the version of NuGet on their default servers, we'll just have to check-in the `project.lock.json` file with our projects.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution of the problem, not sure it is the same for everybody though.

My projects were created with VS2013 and I enabled automatic nuget restore. In VS2013 you get a .nuget solutionfolder and some xml code in your projectfiles.
This is a "old way" restoring nuget packages during msbuild.

The xml code is near the bottom of your cproj files, it should look something like this:

```
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" />
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets'))" />
  </Target>
```

Removing this solution folder and the xml code from the projectfiles (you have to unload the projects first) fixed my problem.

See more information:
https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore#automatic-package-restore-in-visual-studio
(They cleary say at the  top, don't mix the old and new styles ;-))

I hope this helps!